# i want to insert image in mysql through jsp and servlet

Tags: mysql, jsp

My table structure,

```
P_Id Int Primary key
Cat_Id Int Foreign key
Product_Name Nvarchar(50) Not Null
Model_No Nvarchar(50) Not Null
Price Numeric(10,2) Not Null
Photo mediumblob Not Null
Available Varchar(5) Not Null
Display Nvarchar(10) Not Null
Processor Nvarchar(50) Not Null
Platform Nvarchar(50) Not Null
Simcard Nvarchar(50) Not Null
Memory Nvarchar(20) Not Null
Pcamera Nvarchar(50) Not Null
Scamera Nvarchar(50) Not Null
Battery Nvarchar(30) Not Null
Ram Nvarchar(20) Not Null
```

This is my jsp page

```
<form id="form1" action="UploadDBServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<h2 align="center"> Add Product Here:</h2>
  <table border="1" bgcolor="grey" style="color:blue">
    <tr>
        <td>
           <!-- <b>Product_id</b>  -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="pd" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Product Category:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="product">
                <option value="Sony Ericsson">Sony Ericsson</option>
                <option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
                <option value="Htc">HTC</option>
                <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
                <option value="micromax">Micromax</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Product Name:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pname">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Model No:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="mnum">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Price:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="price">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Photo:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="Photo" value="" />
        </td>
     </tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Availability:</b></td>
    <td>Yes <input type="radio" name="al"> No <input
        type="radio" name="al">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Display:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="disp"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Processor:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="proc"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Platform:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="plat"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Sim Card:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sim"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Memory:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mem"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Primary Camera:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pc"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Secondary Camera:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sc"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Battery:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bat"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Ram:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ram"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Add Product" id="box"></td>
    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" id="box"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store image in the database? Normally what programmers do is store the image in a directory and only store the URL in the database; not the image itself. Just imagine how big and slow your database is going to get just with 100 images.

Comment: I am developing online mobile shopping project so i want add product image in database.is der any other way to do that please tell how to do that send me some code samples.thanks for ur response